# I want to fix the coordinates of TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

As shown in the code below, the coordinates of a `Node A` are set to `(0.5\textwidth,0)` to display it in the center. Up to this point, there is no problem.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0.5\textwidth,0)(nodea){NodeA};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, if Node B is placed next to Node A as shown in the following code, the coordinates of Node A will be out of alignment.

```
 \node at (0.5\textwidth,0)(nodea){NodeA};
 \node[left=1cm of nodea](nodeb){NodeB};
```

"V" is Center.
Please tell me !! (from Japanese Student.)

[image: one node]

[image: two nodes]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The final position of Ti*K*Z nodes depends on the placement of the box they live in and the bounding box that is created around the diagram. In general, `0.5\textwidth` does not mean "at the horizontal center of the page". Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) to show how the `tikzpicture` is placed in your document.

Comment: As @JasperHabicht said this is not how TikZ works. (Unless in specific cases with `overlay, remember picture`.) You probably have your picture in a `center` environment or similar which is why your first step works. You could add `trim left=.5\textwidth, trim right=.5\textwidth` to center a TikZ picture horizontally around that *x* coordinate (but you could also just use `0pt` or even better `(nodea)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments to your question--Nodes also take up space whereas coordinates do not-- maybe the answer below satisfies your hunger

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        
        \draw[fill=red] (current page.center) circle (2pt);
        \coordinate[label=-90:NodeA] (a) at (current page.center);
        \coordinate[label=-90:NodeB] (b) at ($(a)+(1cm,0cm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also see ([Fail to draw a line in a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548740/fail-to-draw-a-line-in-a-node/548748#548748))

and ([Line starts next to node (not at it)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580643/line-starts-next-to-node-not-at-it/580646#580646))

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is there way to center only the `x` coordinates?

Comment: @KokiMIZOGUCHI could you please give more details - I could not understand